# Compiling an overleaf template with Texmaker

Tags: xetex, compiling, texmaker, overleaf

I am trying to compile this overleaf template with Texmaker, however I can't get it (I downloaded the .zip file but it still doesn't work).

I attach screenshots (My Texmaker Version: 5.0.3):

[image]
[image]

Comment: the first error is \AddToHook is undefined which indicates that you have an older latex format.

Comment: I reinstalled miktext, I no longer get the first error, but I get the other warnings for example:  `LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `T1/cmr/m/n' in size <7.5> not available` and `"It seems that this file cannot be correctly decoded with the default encoding setting (UTF-8)"`

Comment: the font warning is just for infomation, The encoding error is telling you to configure your editor to save the file in UTF-8. the screenshot shows utf-8 in the editor footline but you presumably have a file copied from elsewhere, Impossible to debug a screenshot.

Comment: I fixed the UTF-8 problem but I get warnings like ´LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `T1/Merriwthr-OsF/m/up' undefined (Font) using `T1/Merriwthr-OsF/m/n' instead´. I debugged the .tex file with texworks and it worked !!!! However, with texmaker I cannot modify the document. What is the problem?

Comment: you could ignore that font warning